# How Can You Turn Off An Event Through A Command? Discord.py

Tags: python, events, discord, discord.py

Im currently trying to make the reaction in the bot response to turn off an moderation event which listens to messages being deleted. This will work as a filter so if the user dont want to log deleted messages they can turn it off by reacting. I've heard of the `wait for` and the `dispatch` function but i currently dont know how it works and couldnt find a tutorial. Any feedback would be amazing as i am a bit stuck and willing to listen to anyone.

Current Code;

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime

class log(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

    mess = False
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        channel = reaction.message.channel
        guild = channel.guild
        message = reaction.message
        if user != self.bot.user:

            if reaction.emoji == '1️⃣':
                check = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Chilly Logs") # Find the Category
                if not check: # If category doesnt exist create the logs

                    cat = await channel.guild.create_category_channel('Chilly Logs')
                    await channel.guild.create_text_channel("Message Logs", category=cat) # Message Logs
                    await channel.guild.create_text_channel("Other Logs", category=cat) # Other Logs
                    await channel.send('**Log Channels Were Succesfully Added!**')
                    await message.remove_reaction('1️⃣', user)
                    return

                else: 
                    await channel.send('**Log Channel Already Exists**')
                    await message.remove_reaction('1️⃣', user)

            if reaction.emoji == '2️⃣':
            
                channel1 = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name="other-logs") # Other Logs
                channel2 = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name="message-logs") # Message Logs
                category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Chilly Logs") # Category/Parent
                if category is not None: # Deletes All The Channels
                    await channel1.delete()
                    await channel2.delete()
                    await category.delete()
                    await channel.send('**Logging Channels Have Been Removed**')
                    await message.remove_reaction('2️⃣', user)
                
                else:
                    await channel.send('**Channels Either Dont Exist Or Have Been Renamed**')
                    await message.remove_reaction('2️⃣', user)

            if reaction.emoji == '❗':



    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Chilly Logging", description = "Chilly Will Log Any Edited, Deleted Messages. More Features & Flexibility Coming Soon", colour = discord.Color.blurple())
        embed.add_field(name="‎‎‎Logging Commands   ‎‎‎", value="1️⃣ - Turn On Server Logging", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="‎ ‎", value= "2️⃣ - Delete & Turn Off Logging", inline=False)
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        emoji = ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '❗']
        response = 3
        for i in range(response):
            await msg.add_reaction(emoji[i])



    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):
        if x == True:
            if not message.author.bot:  # Checks for bot message
                channel = message.channel.name # Channel the deleted message is from
                logchannel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, name='message-logs') # Finds the log channel
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Log", description="", color= discord.Color.red()) # Embeds
                embed.add_field(name="Message sent by {} has been deleted in `{}`" .format(message.author.display_name, channel), value=message.content, inline=True,)
                embed.set_footer(text='User ID: {} | Message ID: {}' .format(message.author.id, message.id))          
                await logchannel.send(embed=embed) # Finally sends the embed to log channel
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
        if not after.author.bot:    
            if before.content != after.content:
                channel = after.channel.name # Channel the edited message is from
                logchannel = discord.utils.get(after.guild.channels, name='message-logs') # Finds the log channel
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Log", description="Message edited in `{}` by {}" .format(channel, after.author.display_name), color= discord.Color.red()) # Embeds
                embed.add_field(name="Before", value=before.content, inline=True,)
                embed.add_field(name="After", value=after.content, inline=False,)
                embed.set_footer(text='User ID: {} | Message ID: {}' .format(after.author.id, before.id))
                await logchannel.send(embed=embed) # Finally sends the embed to log channel

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(log(bot))```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [global variable](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp). Simply:

```
Toggle = True
@bot.command()
async def toggle(ctx):
    global Toggle
    # Toggles the variable.
    Toggle = !Toggle

# Example event

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if Toggle:
        # Event's code
    else:
        await message.channel.send("Function disabled")
```

Comment: When i try to do this, it would give me a syntax error at the ```Toggle = !Toggle```

Comment: @Zyb3rWolfi Toggle needs to be a boolean. Or maybe this is just not a python thing and I'm wrong too... You could just do an if check to see if it's true (turn false) or false (turn into true), messy, but works.

Comment: Update: Just do `Toggle = not Toggle`, because python is weird with it's syntax.

Comment: ```NameError: name 'Toggle' is not defined``` Im applying the global variable across 2 events not a command as i got an ```on_reaction_added``` event which listens for reaction on th message

Comment: Nevermind had to set ```Toggle = not Toggle ``` to ```Toggle = False```